# How to concat many styl files (in different directories) to one css-file?

Tags: gulp, stylus

I use gulp and need to merge all my .styl files to 1 master css-file without import to main.styl. How i can make it? I don't like many css files, i wish the only one :) Thanks and sorry for my English.

My gulp tasks:

```
gulp.task('styl', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/helpers/styl/main.styl')
    .pipe(stylus())
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
      browsers: ['last 4 versions'],
      cascade: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/css/'));
});

gulp.task('serve', ['styl'], function() {
  server.init({
    server: 'src',
    notify: true,
    open: true,
    cors: true,
    ui: false
  });
  gulp.watch('src/blocks/**/*.styl', ['styl']);
  gulp.watch('src/helpers/pug/*.pug', ['pug']).on('change', server.reload);
  gulp.watch('src/pages/*.pug', ['pug']).on('change', server.reload);
  gulp.watch('src/blocks/**/*.pug', ['pug']).on('change', server.reload);
  gulp.watch('src/css/main.css').on('change', server.reload);
  run(
    'pretty'
  );
});
```

And main.styl file for import:

```
@import 'src/blocks/block/*'
@import 'src/helpers/block/*'
```

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with import to main?
I think bulk import can resolve your problem. For .scss files you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass-bulk-import, but for other preprocessors you can also find something.

Comment: I tried to use main.styl file (I added this and gulp tasks to the desc question) but watcher doesnt see my edits and page doesnt refresh. Maybe u know what i do wrong? :)

Comment: So problem probably is with wrong path in gulp.watch

Answer (score 0):

Try this change foreach css the `src` to yours

```
  gulp.task( 'concatCSS', function(){
        return gulp.src( [
            'css/bootstrap.min.css',        
            'css/animate.min.css',
            'css/styles.css',
            'css/responsive.css'
        ] )
        .pipe( concat( 'styles.css' ) )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( 'dist/css/' ) );
    } );
```

Comment: I have the only 1 css-file. ConcatCss doesnt work with styl-files

Comment: what you mean ? i miss understand you

Comment: I need merge .styl files, your plugin concatCss works only with .css files